# InputType=phone does not show the text and returns an empty string

Tags: android, android-inputtype

I'm trying to get a phone number but the `EditText` doesn't show the numeric digit and the String `t` is empty. If I start to enter a + sign followed by some numeric value I get only + in `edit.gettext().toString()`.

If I set `inputtype="text"` everything works as normal.

Is it a bug or what?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.narb.test.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Text typed"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:hint="Enter text"
            android:inputType="phone"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txt;
    EditText edit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);

        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

        edit.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                    String t = edit.getText().toString();
                    txt.setText(t);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you remove `edit.setOnKeyListener()` on your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following this worked for me.

You should only return true from onKey if you're handling the input. I.e., move the return true inside your if block and return false otherwise

```
 edit.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                String t = edit.getText().toString();
                txt.setText(t);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: having said that, it's strange that you only have the problem when using phone?

Comment: @narb I tried it for input type number, the same issue I faced there also.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should try this this

```
android:inputType="number"
```

As Input type "number" is that the keyboard allows to switch over to characters and also lets other special characters be entered.

Comment: on top of that number is not phone: you miss the + sign

Answer (score 0):

**If block** will return **true** and write false at the end.

```
 @Override
            protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchview);
                edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
                txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
                edit.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                            String t = edit.getText().toString();
                            txt.setText(t);
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
```